# angular global controller resource to directive controller

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

So i'm at a bit of a roadblock. I've trying to create a little thumbnail gallery with variable number of rows through an attribute, and given an attribute and a collection, it can build the widget.

So the part i'm stuck at is getting the collection from the global controller (a $resource that uses a backend api) passed to the directive controller so I can write the logic to split and section the collection for the number of rows, and fill each row until it's "full".

So the logic is incomplete, because i'm not sure how to approach it. I've tried every technique I can find (using binding '=' and expression '&') to grab this collection from the global scope, but nothing I do seems to give me access to the collection from within my controller. the ONLY success i've had is it working as interpolated html (as you'll see rowlink at the top).

This works! I see the JSON for my projects, but I don't want it there, because I have to manipulate it, how can I get this collection into my controller to be spliced and rebuilt into individual project items?

```
angular.module("slidePresenter",[])
.controller "presenterCtrl", ($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, $compile) ->
  rowLink = $compile('<div presenterRow ngtransclude>{{getItems() | json}}</div>')
  $scope.rowCount = []
  $scope.buildRows = (rows) ->
    $scope.rowCount = (num for num in [rows..1])
  $scope.printRows = ->
    console.log "rowCount is: #{$scope.rowCount.length}"
  $scope.addRows = ->
    angular.forEach $scope.rowCount, (index,value) ->
      console.log value
      clone = rowLink $scope.$parent.$new(), (clone) ->
        $element.append clone.addClass("presenterRow")
      $element.children().each ->
        $(this).height "#{$element.height() / ($scope.rowCount.length + 1)}px"


.directive "presenter", ($compile) ->
  restrict: "A"
  transclude: true
  controller: "presenterCtrl"
  scope: {rows: '=', getItems: '&'}
  compile: (element, attrs, transcludeFn) ->
    return (scope, element, attrs, presenterCtrl) ->
      scope.$watch 'rows', (value) ->
        scope.buildRows(value)
        scope.printRows()
        scope.addRows()



.directive "presenterRow", ->
  restrict: "A"
  replace: true
  require: '^presenter'
  scope: {title: '@', image: '@', thumbnail: '@', snippet: '@', description: '@'}
  compile: (element, attrs, linker) ->
    return (scope, element, attrs, presenterCtrl) ->
```

That's everything I want encapsulated in this widget/component... then for the global space

```
angular.module('appolio', ['slidePresenter','ngResource'])

.factory 'Projects' , ($resource) ->
    $resource("/projects/:id", {id: '@id'})


.controller 'mainCtrl' , ($compile, $scope, Projects) ->
  $scope.projects = Projects.query()

  $scope.getItems = ->
    $scope.projects
```

and of course the markup

```
<body ng-app="appolio">
  <div class="viewBox" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="presenter" presenter getItems="getItems()" rows='4'></div>
```

I've tried using '&expression' '=binding' , passing the array directly in as the $scope.projects and simply doing something like

```
scope: {items: '='}
```

and in markup

```
<presenter items="projects"></presenter>
```

but this doesn't work for me? when I try to access this within the controller, the value I get for "projects" by accessing the attribute is simply the string "projects", but $scope.projects has a value the mainCtrl, so at this point- I don't care how... I just need to find out how to copy this collection into my  directive controller and modify it  =/

Comment: This could be due to async nature of resource all. Can you try to put a $watch on the projects collection within your directive controller and see if this collection changes.

Comment: Gave it a try, but no luck i'm afraid.